# Why does word2vec have a sparsity problem

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec

If the weights are trained with enough examples, then they shouldn't be `0`.

From what I understand the sparsity problem of word2vec comes from the fact that most of its weights are `0`.

Word2vec has weights from the input to the projection and from the projection to the output.

Comment: What is a "sparsity problem"?

Answer (score 2):

Be more precise about the "sparsity problem" of word2vec.

The weights learned by word2vec are the dense word representations of dimension *d*. These weights are not equal to 0.

The only sparsity I see is the encoding of the input words : they are encoded using "one-hot encoding". This means that when you have *V* words in your vocabulary, each word is encoded as a sparse vector of dimension *V*.

I suggest you to take a look at this site which explains word2vec.

> http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/19/word2vec-tutorial-the-skip-gram-model/